# React redux is not updating components

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

React app doesn't update components after reducing new state. After first render, no matter what actions i do, there is no updates in react components.
I tried to find some state mutation in reducers, but there are none. I have no idea what is a problem.

Here is repo: https://github.com/ithrasil/rainbeat/tree/bug

I would appreciate any help

one of reducers:

```
export default function(
state={ 
    received: false,
    status: false, 
  primaryList: [], 
  secondaryList: [], 
  query: "" 
}, 
action) {

switch(action.type) {

case "RECEIVE_STATUS":
  state.received = action.payload;
  break;

    case "SEARCH_STATUS":
        state.status = action.payload;
        break;

    case "PRIMARY_LIST_UPDATE":
        state.primaryList = action.payload;
        break;

    case "SECONDARY_LIST_UPDATE":
        state.secondaryList = action.payload;
        break;

    case "QUERY_UPDATE":
        state.query = action.payload;
        localStorage.setItem('query', action.payload);
        break;
    }

    return state;
}
```

One of containers
https://github.com/ithrasil/rainbeat/blob/bug/src/containers/left/search.jsx

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: Please post some code from components that are not updated and reducers, so that we can help more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating the state. That is why your components are not rendering

```
export default function(state={ id: 0 }, action) {
 var newState; 
   switch(action.type) {
        case "CHANGE_CARD":
          newState={...state, id: action.payload}
          break;
      }

      return newState;
    }
```